Azure Search HTML Strip CharFilter Not Removing HTML from JSON Metadata in Index
I am using Azure Search to index content from SharePoint, and I'm encountering an issue where HTML tags are not being removed from JSON metadata despite using the html_strip character filter. Here is a detailed breakdown of my setup and the issue:
Data Source Configuration:
The data is fetched from SharePoint and contains fields like edSubProcess which are stored in JSON format with HTML content. Here is an example of how the metadata appears:
{
    "name" : "sharepoint-car-index",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_name", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_path", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_content_type", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_last_modified", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_size", "type": "Edm.Int64", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "edSubProcess", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer": "htmlAnalyzer"}
    ],
      "analyzers": [
      {
        "name": "htmlAnalyzer",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "charFilters": [ "html_strip" ],
        "tokenizer": "standard_v2"
      }
    ]
}

Result:
"edSubProcess": "{\r\n  \"Label\": \"004.01. Traffic\",\r\n  \"TermGuid\": \"e1d2fc6d-769c-4735-be6f-abb8039b827c\",\r\n  \"WssId\": 946\r\n}",

Problem:
Despite using the html_strip character filter, the HTML tags within the JSON metadata are not being stripped away, and the metadata is still stored with all HTML elements intact in Azure Search.
Questions:
Is the html_strip character filter appropriate for removing HTML from within JSON strings, or does it only work on direct HTML content?
Are there any known limitations or considerations when applying html_strip to fields that store JSON as a string?
What alternative approaches can I consider to strip HTML content from JSON strings before indexing in Azure Search?
Any insights or recommendations on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
I configured my Azure Search index to use the html_strip character filter with the hope that it would remove any HTML content from the JSON strings in the metadata fields such as edSubProcess. Specifically, I expected the html_strip filter to parse through the string values of JSON and remove any HTML tags found therein, leaving behind clean text.
What I did was apply a custom analyzer (htmlAnalyzer) that includes the html_strip character filter and the standard_v2 tokenizer to the fields storing JSON data. The aim was to cleanse these fields from any HTML formatting before they were indexed, as I believed this setup would automatically strip out HTML based on the filter’s capabilities documented by Lucene.
However, the results were not as expected. The HTML content was not removed from the JSON strings. The metadata still appears in the index with all the HTML elements intact. It seems like the html_strip character filter did not parse the JSON string data or the filter was unable to remove HTML from within these strings.
This outcome suggests that either I might have misunderstood the capabilities of the html_strip filter when it comes to handling JSON encapsulated strings, or there may be a specific configuration that I missed.
Update:
In addition to my initial attempts with the html_strip character filter, I have also experimented with using a CustomAnalyzer that incorporates a PatternReplaceCharFilter. Specifically, I utilized a regular expression /\\r\\n/g aiming to clean up the field by removing newline characters, but this approach also did not lead to successful removal of HTML tags from the JSON strings. The metadata remains unchanged with HTML content still present. This result further complicates the issue, indicating that the approach to cleaning embedded HTML in JSON strings may require a different strategy than anticipated.
"fields": [
        { "name": "edSubProcess", "type": "Edm.String", "retrievable": true, "key": false, "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer": "custom_cgl_analyzer"}
    ],
      "analyzers": [
      {
        "name": "custom_cgl_analyzer",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "charFilters": [ "md_replacer", "html_strip" ],
        "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "standard_v2"
      }
    ],
      "charFilters": [
      {
        "name": "md_replacer",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.PatternReplaceCharFilter",
        "pattern": "/\\r\\n/g",
        "replacement": ""
      }
    ]

